# spring boot + apache camel + jpa

Tags: apache, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm creating a new project using spring boot + apache camel + jpa.

It's supposed to be very simple, but something is misconfigured and I can't find what is it.

The apache camel route seems to be working but the database connection seems not.

Main app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PolicyUpdateWebServiceApplication {
protected static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PolicyUpdateWebServiceApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplication(PolicyUpdateWebServiceApplication.class).run(args);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/webservices/*");
}

@Bean(name= Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
public SpringBus springBus() {
    return new SpringBus();
}
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "TransactionInfo"
)
@XmlCDATA({"bookingXML"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "TransactionInfo",
    propOrder = {"transactionId", "CCVB", "quoteNumber", "policyNumber", "bookingXML", "creationDate", "lastModified", "status", "statusDescription"}
)
public class TransactionInfo implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2368497973443507661L;

@Id
private String transactionId;

@Embedded
@Column(nullable = false)
private CCVB CCVB;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
private String quoteNumber;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
private String policyNumber;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String bookingXML;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XMLDateAdapter.class)
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Date creationDate;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XMLDateAdapter.class)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Date lastModified;

@Column(length = 4, nullable = false)
private IntegrationStatus status;

@Column(length = 100)
private String statusDescription;
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionInfoRepository extends     CrudRepository<TransactionInfo, String> {
TransactionInfo findByTransactionId(String name);
TransactionInfo save(TransactionInfo TransactionInfo);
}
```

Service:

```
public interface TransactionInfoService {
void saveTransactionInfo(TransactionInfo transactionInfo);
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
@Component("transactionInfoService")
@Transactional
public class TransactionInfoServiceImpl implements TransactionInfoService {
@Autowired
TransactionInfoRepository transactionInfoRepository;

public void saveTransactionInfo(TransactionInfo transactionInfo) {
    transactionInfoRepository.save(transactionInfo);
}
}
```

During the apache route... I have the code:

```
public class PolicyPublishProcessor implements Processor {

@Autowired
TransactionInfoService transactionInfoService;

TransactionInfo transactionInfo = new TransactionInfo();

// save a couple of customers
transactionInfoService.saveTransactionInfo(transactionInfo);
```

However, when I turn the debug... I can see that the transactionInfoService variable, which is supposed to be injected... is coming null.

Anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Make your Camel Processor a Spring bean via the `@Component` annotation.